# c# Retrieving information from a control in a dynamic created tab

Tags: c#, combobox, tabcontrol

I'm new to c#, but I came across a problem that google hasn't answered for me.

In my code, I am able to create TabPages in a TabControl based on user input.  (ex. If I want 5 items, my code will create 5 tabs all with their own controls (ComboBoxes)).

My problem is getting data from those ComboBoxes.  I want to be able to pull the selected data from each ComboBox for each 'item' (TabPage) I have created.  Since they are created dynamically, I can't just reference directly (eg. TabControl.TabPages[n].comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) because 'comboBox1' will only reference the last TabPage I've created.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It will be better if we can see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy solution would be to put the comboboxes in a list, like this:

```
    int tabCount = 5;
    tabControl.TabPages.Clear();

    List<ComboBox> comboboxes = new List<ComboBox>(tabCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++)
    {
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboboxes.Add(comboBox);
        tabPage.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    }

    // You can access the values using the 'comboboxes' list now.
```

A better (but more complex) solution would be to implement a data model and bind the comboboxes to this model. This way you won't care about the concrete control (i.e. TabPage, ComboBox, etc.) that represents the values.

Comment: This should work - however, now you need to keep the tabs list in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have named the ComboBox in each tab the same I suggest that you designate the tab container as a naming container, reference the tab and then use FindControl to find the ComboBox.
The class representing the tab must implement INamingContainer. This causes all controls within the tab to have their control id prefixed with the id of the naming container.
Here is an example of a naming container http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/using-inamingcontainer-in-controls/